# Recurring function to reset variable/counter at midnight (moment.js, node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I want to reset a variable during midnight. Every night.
I'm trying to build this function with Moment.js for Node but I can't seem to get the recurring part to work properly.

This is what I got so far.

```
// Calculate time to midnight
function timeToMidnight(){
    var midnight = new Date();
    midnight.setHours(0,0,0,0); 
    var now = new Date();
    var msToMidnight = midnight - now;
    console.log(' it is ' + msToMidnight + 'ms until midnight');
    return msToMidnight;
};

// Reset counter at midnight
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("midnight, do something");
}, timeToMidnight());
```

How can I best make it recurring at midnight, every night?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run a cron job which issues an API call via curl or something to the node app.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get this solution at all.

Comment: All operating systems have a utility called "cron", which is designed to reliably execute some job at regular intervals. You can set up cron to issue an HTTP request such as `http://my-server/its-midnight` at midnight each day. Then, you set up your node application to listen for and handle requests to that URL and do the necessary thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/), consider instead this implementation

```
var moment = require('moment');

function timeToMidnight() {
   var now = new Date();
   var end = moment().endOf("day");

   return end - now + 1000;
}
```

Like your function, this takes *now* milliseconds and calculates the number of milliseconds until midnight, but this is supported directly when using moment, which is nice.  Add 1 extra second (1000 milliseconds) to get to the next day.

A typical pattern is for a function to call itself after a timeout.

```
function roundMidnight() {
   console.log('at midnight');
   setTimeout(roundMidnight,timeToMidnight());
}

setTimeout(roundMidnight,timeToMidnight());
```

Pretty generic, in fact depending on the value returned, you could schedule anything anytime, pretty useful, seem like someone must have thought of that.

#### node-schedule

> > A cron-like and not-cron-like job scheduler for Node.

And they did.  Maybe what you really want is [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-schedule).  It looks like it's not really actively developed now, though.